# How to have a thread wait untill all others have finished reading in order to write

Tags: c++, multithreading

OS: Windows 10
Programming language: C++

I wrote a program which originally was not intended to be multi threaded. Now I am in the process of splinting it on to multiple threads.

At this  point it all revolves around one unordered_map, there is only one thread that is modifying the map and all others just read.

So basically one write multiple reads.

I have thus far implemented mtx.lock and mtx.unlock in the write and that works just fine noone can read while the write process is taking place.

The problem comes into being when the WRITE takes place while someone is reading.

I understand that I could theoretically put the same mtx.lock and mtx.unlock on every read and that should solve the problem. But this is something I am desperately trying to avoid as there are a lot of points where the data is read and I would have to implement a hundred or more locks which is really inconvenient for me as it would be for anyone probably.

My question is:
Can I have the thread that is doing the Writing wait until everybody is done with reading and  then call locks and do the writing. And of course how would one go about doing this.

Comment: so you want read have higher priority(even the data may be outdated)?

Comment: Yes regardless of the data being outdated I need the threads to be able to read. without causing any problems. And preferably without implementing locks on every read rather instead I wanted to see if the Write thread can just check if everybody is done reading and conduct a write.

Comment: "I understand that I could theoretically put the same mtx.lock and mtx.unlock on every read" - theoretically? Because just 2 paragraphs earlier you said "I have thus far implemented mtx.lock and mtx.unlock in the read".

Comment: Apologies I meant Write, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is basically a read/write lock. This allows either multiple readers or a single writer to have access at any one time, but not both.

This can be achieved in C++17 by using `std::shared_mutex`, or (for older C++) by using `boost::shared_mutex`. The shared mutex allows two levels of access, either *shared* access, which your readers would request, or *exclusive* access which you would request when you want to write.

Answer (score 0):

"Can I have the thread that is doing the Writing wait until everybody is done with reading and then call locks and do the writing?"

Solution you ask about looks opposite to what you trying to achieve as you have multiple reading places. Every time you read you would have to send message (lock).

Generally it sounds very bad, but nevertheless:
If your write happens incidentally, you can send "lock" message to reading threads. Reading thread will receive a message / an event, when you do occasionally write. Reading threads would then lock for a moment and send a message (it's ok to write) back to writing thread. After write complete writing threads will inform reading threads it's ok to read.

[Check this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)

Comment: I know of this solution I am trying to see if anyone knows a work around for this so that the writing thread just checks if anyone is reading prior to calling its own locks. So that I can have locks in just one place and not implement them at every read as there are really a lot of points where the read happens and it is just convenient to add locks at all of these places.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution might be a `std::atomic<std::unordered_map*>`.

Atomic variables can be updated while being read. You can't guarantee whether the readers get the old or the new pointer, but they'll get one of the two and not a random value.

This is easy, but has one drawback - how do you know when it's safe to `delete` the old map that you've retired?

There is an alternative - `std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map>`. The readers, *when reading* will make a private copy of the global pointer. This ensures the version of the map they're using stays alive. The writer thread just calls `std::make_shared` when it has a new map, and assigns it to the global pointer.

`std::shared_ptr` is thread-safe *enough*. Reading it is thread-safe, and there are no conflicting writers (each reader thread overwrites its own copy.)

Ex.

```
class Writer {
  std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<Foo>> m_map;
  void add(Foo f) {
     auto copy = std::make_shared<std::unordered_map<Foo>>(m_map);
     copy.insert(f);
     m_map = foo; // thread-safe
  }
public:
  std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<Foo>> getMap() { return m_map; }
};
```

Comment: Is there any chance that I could trouble you for an example. As I have been trying to integrate this without much success.

Comment: @ChronicUser: added